# How to resolve the issue "The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback" in Cygnite PHP Framework

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am using Cygnite PHP Framework. I found cool, looading blazing fast though. I have installed (v1.2.1) but Cygnite debugger shows warning in the bottom right bar as follows.

```
"PHP Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, 
use preg_replace_callback instead in 
.../cygnite/vendor/cygnite/framework/src/Cygnite/Helpers/Inflector.php:69"
```

How do I resolve this issue ? Anyone help?

Comment: Your best bet is to file a bug report

Comment: it looks like they have resolved this in `v1.2.3` update!